# SQL Regex for finding domain from a common name

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have the following sample data set in one of my tables:


sub1.domain.com

domain.com

sub1.sub2.domain.com

*.domain.com

**Updated**
Also including ccTLD

 *.domain.co.uk

is there a way/regex in Oracle that can help me extract just the domain name - "domain.com" from the string.I have been trying a few regexes but it dint work out.
Thanks for the help

Comment: `uk` is the ccTLD, not `co.uk`. If you want to get `domain.co.uk` you have to make a separate case for it because we have no way of telling the difference between `sub1.domain.com` and `domain.co.uk`.

Comment: I have updated my answer for `co.uk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following regex matching something_without_a_dot.something_without_a_dot from the end of the string. You'll get the answer in the first group. If you need the TLD also, you can enclose everything in `()` except the `$`.

```
([^.]+)\.[^.]+$
```

In SQL, that gives:

```
SQL> select regexp_replace('sub1.sub2.domain.com', '^.*?([^.]+)\.[^.]+$', '\1') from dual;

REGEXP
------
domain
```

The non-greedy `.*?` at the start allows you to ignore the start of the string.

To get the domain name plus the TLD:

```
SQL> select regexp_replace('sub1.sub2.domain.com', '^.*?([^.]+\.[^.]+)$', '\1') from dual;

REGEXP_REP
----------
domain.com
```

To take into account `co.uk`:

```
SQL> select regexp_replace('sub1.sub2.domain.co.uk', '^.*?([^.]+\.(co\.uk|[^.]+))$', '\1') from dual;

REGEXP_REPLA
------------
domain.co.uk
```

Comment: To make this generic(both for TLDs and ccTLDs) probably i need to add all the ccTLDs in the regex....

Comment: @Anup ccTLD are just like other TLDs. They are at the end of the FQDN. So I don't think they need a specific treatment, except if the preceding sub-domain has to be included like in `co.uk` where the `co` is included in the result. I mean `uk` is the ccTLD, not `co.uk`.

Answer (score 0):

While I was typing my answer the guy above gave a good regex.  I'm thinking you could use REGEXP_REPLACE in your select statement.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(fieldname, '([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$', '\1\.\2') as fieldname
```

Comment: IMHO that will have a zero effect because the matched part will be replaced by itself.

Comment: Thanks William...i tried select REGEXP_REPLACE('abc.domain.com', '([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$', '\1\.\2') from dual; it gives output as abc.domain\.com

Comment: Yes, the dot doesn't have to be escaped in the replace string. If corrected, it gives the same string because of the replace operation of `REGEXP_REPLACE`.