# Get domain from URL in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a database that contains website URL's. From those URL's I'd like to extract the domain name. Here are two (quiet different) examples:

```
http://www.example.com       -> example.com
example.co.uk/dir/index.html -> example.co.uk
```

In order to do this I am using a regular expression and the functions REGEXP_SUBSTR and REGEXP_REPLACE that Oracle provides. I am using replace to replace the preceding `http[s]` and the `www.` with an empty string (deleting it). Then I use substring to get the string between the beginning and the first `/` or if there is no `/` the whole string. My code looks like this:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(website_url, '^http[s]?://(www\.)?|^www\.', '', 1), '(.+?)(/|$)')
```

Everything works as expected, except the fact that my regex fails to exclude the `/`:

```
example.com/dir/index.html -> example.com/
```

I would like to get rid of the `/`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the hints in the answers I finally got it working!

The code I am using now looks like this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(website_url, '(http[s]?://)?(www\.)?(.*?)((/|:)(.)*|$)', '\3')
```

Thanks for the help everybody!

Answer (score 7):

Use this :

```
WITH tab AS 
 (SELECT 'https://www.example.co.uk/dir/index.html' AS website_url 
    FROM dual)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(website_url, '^http[s]?://(www\.)?|^www\.', '', 1), '\w+(\.\w+)+') 
  FROM tab;
```

output:

```
|REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(W|
--------------------------------
|example.co.uk                 |
```

Comment: This works very nice! Thank you very much. But sadly it doesn't work for URL's that include a `-` for example the URl `www.top.i-am-a-example.com` gives `top.i` I tried but I can't fix it. Do you know how?

Comment: Adding permissible range could be one solution to this. `REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(website_url, '^http[s]?://(www\.)?|^www\.', '', 1), '[a-z,A-Z,0-9,-]+(\.\w+)+')`

Comment: Yes adding a range seems to be the only option. Using the your code I still get `top.i`. I am not an expert on regex, so I don't know why... Looks correct to me

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether oracle supports the `?:` to exclude a group or not.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(website_url, '^(?:(?:http[s]?://)?www\.)?(.*?)(?:/.*|$)', '\1')
```

If it doesn't, then this one:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(website_url, '^((http[s]?://)?www\.)?(.*?)(/.*|$)', '\3')
```

Comment: As far as I can see it Oracle does not support `?:` the second works as expected, but somehow it does not work for urls like: `www.example.com/dir/index.html` it returns: `example.comdir/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex matching something_without_a_dot.something_without_a_dot from the end of the string. You'll get the answer in the first group. If you need the TLD also, you can enclose everything in `()` except the `$`.

```
([^.]+)\.[^.]+$
```

In SQL, that gives:

```
SQL> select regexp_replace('sub1.sub2.domain.com', '^.*?([^.]+)\.[^.]+$', '\1') from dual;

REGEXP
------
domain
```

The non-greedy `.*?` at the start allows you to ignore the start of the string.

To get the domain name plus the TLD:

```
SQL> select regexp_replace('sub1.sub2.domain.com', '^.*?([^.]+\.[^.]+)$', '\1') from dual;

REGEXP_REP
----------
domain.com
```

To take into account `co.uk`:

```
SQL> select regexp_replace('sub1.sub2.domain.co.uk', '^.*?([^.]+\.(co\.uk|[^.]+))$', '\1') from dual;

REGEXP_REPLA
------------
domain.co.uk
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840760/sql-regex-for-finding-domain-from-a-common-name)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using (http)uritype and extract host from that?